# Is Base64 deterministic (Apache Commons lib or otherwise)?

Tags: java, scala, base64, apache-commons

I'm using the Base64 encoder from the Apache Commons library. Now either something funny is going on with my runtime/IDE, or their implementation of Base64 encoding (or Base64 as a specification) is non-deterministic:

```
val test = Base64.encodeBase64("hello".getBytes).toString
val test2 = Base64.encodeBase64("hello".getBytes).toString
val test3 = Base64.encodeBase64("hello".getBytes).toString
```

Each of the above produce different results. Is this expected? I'm writing this in Scala...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equivalent Java code for the Scala code which you have posted will be :

```
String test = Base64.encodeBase64("hello".getBytes()).toString();
String test2 = Base64.encodeBase64("hello".getBytes()).toString();
String test3 = Base64.encodeBase64("hello".getBytes()).toString();
```

This will print the `toString()` of the `byte[]` array object for each `Base64.encodeBase64("hello".getBytes())` which will be different objects and hence different output to the console. It executes the [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method of `Object` class which, according to the Javadocs says :

*Returns a string representation of the object.*

*The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.*

To get the correct `String` representation , use [Arrays.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(byte[])) method. A sample Java code to print the correct result is as below :

```
String test = Arrays.toString(Base64.encodeBase64("hello".getBytes()));
String test2 = Arrays.toString(Base64.encodeBase64("hello".getBytes()));
String test3 = Arrays.toString(Base64.encodeBase64("hello".getBytes()));
```

Comment: Ahhh! It was my abuse of Array.toString on the byte array! D'oh! Thanks :)

Comment: Just a hint: don't use getBytes() on a String without specifying the encoding - especially when you transfer it to another system which is likely the case when doing base64 encoding. Otherwise you might get problems if the default encoding differs on the machines where base64encoding and base64decoding takes place.

Comment: One easy one of doing that in Scala is to '.toList.toString', lists always prints it's contents rather than the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Calling toString() on an array probably returns JVM memory address of the individual arrays thus, each of the Base64.encodeBase64("hello".getBytes()) would return different arrays and a toString() on each of it will return different addresses.

Comment: Not necessarily the memory address . Please refer the Javadocs.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot Yes I know it is something referred as "identity hash code" which in turn can be thought of as a memory address in lay man's term. The reason I used the word 'probably'